# How can I threaten with a whip?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, weapons

Is there any way to threaten with a whip aside from taking 3 feats to get [Improved whip mastery](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/combat-feats/improved-whip-mastery-combat), which still only increases your range by 5 ft?

I found [one forum post](http://brilliantgameologists.com/boards/index.php?topic=8991.0) with a solution but that is to cheesy and doesn't fit my character anyway.

For some context: I am building a defense oriented character whose goal is to keep enemies away from allies and to keep their focus on him. He is a [Paladin](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/core-classes/paladin) with the [Sacred Shield](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/core-classes/paladin/archetypes/paizo---paladin-archetypes/sacred-shield) and [Oath Against Savagery](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/core-classes/paladin/archetypes/paizo---paladin-archetypes/oathbound-paladin/oath-against-savagery) archetypes. We are also using the [Mythic rules](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/mythic) and he is a [Guardian](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/mythic/mythic-heroes/mythic-paths---paizo-inc/guardian) specifically.

I don't mind a bit of optimization because this build is suffering a bit as I am trying to do something that, as far as I can tell, doesn't work very well.

Comment: Indiana Jones and the Last Crusade came to my mind. Looking at and grasping his whip, the Grail Knight says, "You are strangely dressed for a knight."

Comment: This is an easy one, you just point your whip at a guy and say "I'm gonna kill you raaaaagh."

Comment: Paladin with a whip? Are you playing as Simon Belmont?

Comment: If you want to be cheesy, IIRC the Urumi from the Serpent's Skull Adventure Path was basically 3.5's spiked chain. While there is no formal errata for the AP, both UC and UE contain completely different versions of the weapon without reach. For bonus cheese, argue that SS predates UE, making it the primary source or something...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### No

There is no other way to allow you to threaten with a Whip outside of taking these three feats.  The only advantage using a whip instead of a reach weapon will provide is allow you to threaten squares adjacent to you.

> While wielding a whip, you threaten the area of your natural reach plus 5 feet

Improved Whip Mastery will allow you to threaten 10 ft. away from you at any time for the cost of 3 feats.  If you have any primary spellcasters along, an [Enlarge Person](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/e/enlarge-person) or [Long Arm](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/l/long-arm) spell, will increase your natural reach to reach to 15ft.

According to [James Jacob](http://paizo.com/threads/rzs2l7ns&page=427?Ask-James-Jacobs-ALL-your-Questions-Here#21334), Using a whip with a natural reach of 15ft will allow you a total attack reach of 45ft.  This doesn't affect your threatened range, which will always be Natural Reach + 5ft, for a total of threatened area of 5-20ft.

---

While it would be very feat-intensive, I would suggest if you want to keep enemies away from your allies, to look at a tripping build.

Any time an opponent moves through a square in your threatened area, you are able to trip them to prevent any further movement. Standing up will actually allow you and any ally in range the chance to beat on them even further with an additional AoO, before they risk being tripped by moving again.

Pick up the [Improved Trip](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/combat-feats/improved-trip-combat---final) and [Greater Trip](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/combat-feats/greater-trip-combat---final) feats to get a +4 bonus to tripping, and let you have a free AoO whenever you successfully trip an enemy as well.

If you wanted to avoid the Feat Tax for using a Whip, while under the effect of Enlarge Person and Long Arm, you may be able to use a [Spiked Chain](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/equipment---final/weapons/weapon-descriptions/chain-spiked) or a [Rapier](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/equipment---final/weapons/weapon-descriptions/rapier) to threaten squares 5ft-15ft with finesse, or any Reach,Trip [Weapon](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/equipment---final/weapons) will allow you to threaten 15ft-25ft instead.

Comment: -1 for multiple reasons: 1. OP already mentions Improved Whip Mastery and is looking for alternatives to using three feats on this. 2. While tripping will definitely help with the character, it is not part of the question. 3. Pathfinder's Spiked Chain [does not have reach](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/equipment---final/weapons).

Comment: Also, you're unable to prevent someone from standing up by tripping with an AoO, because an AoO happens before the triggering action. Thus, they're still prone when you make your attack, and finish standing up afterwards.

Comment: Thanks for your comments guys, I've updated the answer to address these issues.

Comment: You are able to ready an action to trip them as soon as they have stood up, but it costs you a standard, and you only have one, so it doesn't help if you tripped a bunch of people with AoOs.

Answer (score 0):

[The Scorpion Whip (from Ultimate Combat)](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/equipment---final/weapons/weapon-descriptions/whip-scorpion) can be used either as a normal 'light performance weapon' or as a whip if you are also proficient with a whip. There aren't detailed instructions, but it appears that you can choose which type of weapon it functions as whenever you use it; allowing you to attack with it as a whip and the use it with an attack of opportunity as light performance weapon. But it will still only let you threaten 5ft.

See HeyICanChan's answer from [this question](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/58688/8610) regarding this Scorpion Whip (there are two versions of it). The accepted answer is about the other scorpion whip.

I've seen some Aid Another builds use a whip to good effect, as it merely requires you to be in position to make a melee attack, rather than require you to actually threaten. The [Bodyguard feat](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/combat-feats/bodyguard-combat) is often part of those builds and may be of interest to your stated goals.

Comment: O, the [scorpion whip](http://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/58688/8610). We meet again.

Comment: @HeyICanChan and Isaac Does the Scorpion whip threaten though it says it works like a whip which means it wouldn't threaten. I will be getting bodyguard though.

Comment: @Aaron The scorpion whip can threaten at 5ft - though you can find better weapons to threaten close - Or at 5ft-10ft with Improved Whip Mastery - same as a normal whip.

Comment: See HeyICanChan's answer in his link (The accepted answer is about the other Scorpion Whip)