# Does improved whip mastery benefit from long arm?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, spells, reach

I have built a whip character. The goal of this character is size from enlarge person, increasing reach with long arm, and attacking everything within 45 feet reach using whirlwind attack. I have invested the feats to take improved whip mastery so I can now threaten with the whip equal to natural reach +5 feet. So medium is 10, and large is 15. What I am trying to figure out is if the long arm spell would add to this threatened reach making this threatened space medium 15 and large 20.

[Long Arm](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/l/long-arm)

> Your arms temporarily grow in length, increasing your reach with those limbs by 5 feet.

It says my reach increases, but not my natural reach. Does this distinction matter?

The [answer](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/65367/23058) to "[how can I threaten with a whip](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/65354/23058)" does not directly answer my question.

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing about a notion of "natural reach" in the rules of *long arm*. You quoted the whole text. "Natural reach" is probably "reach before taking into account the weapon's reach property" but [that's not an official rule](http://www.giantitp.com/forums/showthread.php?256373-What-is-natural-reach), just the one that makes the more sense.

What that text means is that the +5 feet increase only applies to your arms: if you have a bite, gore, wing buffet... attack, it won't benefit from the increase. But the whip definitely will [as long as you hold it in your hands](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/races/3rd-party-races/silver-games/ponykind/).

However I suspect the [reach property of weapons](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/gamemastering/combat/space-reach-threatened-area-templates/) doesn't stack with other bonus to reach the way you think. If you stand on square 0, square 1 is next to you, square 2 next to it, etc, a longspear with long arm let you threaten squares 3 and 4. If you are also enlarged you would threaten squares 4, 5 and 6. In your case (whip, whip mastery, long arm) you threaten squares between 8 and 12, or between 11 and 15 if enlarged.

Comment: Hmm, if this is true then lunge would be a feat worth taking as well